# vscode-icons not accessible from extension running under WSL

Tags: vscode-extensions, wsl-2

i have my own vscode extension that depends upon the `vscode-icons` extension....  everything works fine under windows, though i'm having an issue under WSL....

my extension works correctly when installed in WSL; but i've explicitly call out `vscode-icons` as a dependency, i receive this message when starting-up:

[image]

unlike many other extensions, my understanding is that `vscode-icons` is one that "stays on the local side" when running under WSL....  when i look at the list of installed extension, i see `vscode-icons` highlighted on the LOCAL side but greyed-out on the WSL side; and of course there is no option to install this extension under WSL....

suggestions anyone????

---

more information....  if i remove the dependency on vscode-icons from my extension's `package.json`, i can indeed load remotely....

my problem now is that i can't seem to customize the vscode-icons configuration as when everything is running locally....

in my extension, i **dynamically** associate icons with certain folders by programmatically changing some bindings in the `settings.json` file; vscode-icons then exposes a command (which can be invoked remote->local) which effectively refreshes the display....

right now, i don't see **any** icons being displayed next to the folders of interest....

standing back, i'm looking for an approach to associate icons with a folder/file that has some "semantic" property....

thoughts???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are dealing with this scenario (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions#handling-dependencies-with-remote-extensions), and I’m not sure you would be able to change how vscode-icons extension works.

But, I wonder if your extension *really needs* to be installed on remote. I mean, unless you need full access  to the workspace, maybe you could keep your extension as UI (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions#architecture-and-extension-kinds). Doing so, you would still have access to the vscode-icons API/support.

Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately, my extension needs access to the workspace -- create files, launch tools, etc....  reading your references, i'm a little confused about this section (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions#handling-dependencies-with-remote-extensions)....  i **only** depend on vsicons commands; no APIs....  should i fork vsicons and edit package.json to contain "api": "none" ????

Comment: Based on that documentation, I would say the dependency you are trying to achieve is not doable, but I'm not sure how you "depends on" vscode-icons (API, commands or simply the icon ids somehow). A quick look on their repo, I noticed this https://github.com/vscode-icons/vscode-icons/issues/2415#issuecomment-615120782? Have you seen this?

Comment: that's a reasonable suggestion, which i'll try at some point....  my current "workaround" is to actually install vscode "natively" in WSL -- which does in fact work....  in general, i have a "remote docker container" that i want to use under vscode (with WSL being a special case)....  i believe i can simply install vscode into the docker container -- where it will run "locally" and have no problems accessing vscode-icons....  this approach is actually preferable for my use-case:  having a completed "curated dev envrionment" within a docker container....